# spark-submit error: Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g --jars, but enough of memory on the system

Tags: java, apache-spark, hail

I am running a spark job:

```
spark-submit --master spark://ai-grisnodedev1:7077 --verbose --conf spark.driver.port=40065 --driver-memory 4g
--jars /opt/seqr/.conda/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hail/hail-all-spark.jar 
--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/opt/seqr/.conda/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hail/hail-all-spark.jar 
--conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=./hail-all-spark.jar ./hail_scripts/v02/convert_vcf_to_hail.py ./hgmd_pro_2019.4_hg38.vcf -ht 
--genome-version 38 --output ./hgmd_pro_2019.4_hg38.ht
```

And the command gives an error:

> Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g --jars
>   Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>   Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

I checked memory:

[image]

So, it seems to be fine. I checked `java`:

```
(py37) -bash-4.2$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)
```

Then I checked in `Chrome` whether `spark` is running at `ai-grisnodedev1:7077` and it does with one worker. If I use `ipython` I am able to run the simple `install` example at https://hail.is/docs/0.2/getting_started.html:

```
import hail as hl
mt = hl.balding_nichols_model(n_populations=3, n_samples=50, n_variants=100)
mt.count()
```

So, `Hail` that is depending on `Spark` is working too. Maybe my command is malformed or some files are corrupted?s But then the error is very misleading. What could I do to try to debug this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just posted the question and fixed it right away although was pretty desperate. The issue was that I was copy pasting the command in several editors and back and some wrong characters probably were present after `--driver-memory 4g`. I just deleted spaces (that may not have been spaces) and reinserted them, and it started working. It shard to say why, maybe `tab` or `newline` messed it up somehow. I was using `Microsoft One Note` - maybe it is doing some modifications of spaces...

Answer (score 3):

I also had the issue. Anyhow, I was using `pySpark`.
For me it was the issue that `spark.executor.memory` accepted e.g. `16gb`, while the `spark.driver.memory`only accepted `16g`-> The **b** in *g**b*** caused the error (a little unintuitive to be honest).